# Find equation of line given length of a segment and point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

can anyone please help me with the following. I need to find possible equations of a line whose length of a segment is 5 between the lines with the following equations:
$$x+2y+1=0$$
$$x+2y-1=0$$
And it contains a point P(-5,4). So far I've written this:
$$y-4 = k(x+5)$$
But I am stuck there, I've created a system of equations but messed something up and can't get a solution, so any help would be much appreciated, cheers :)

Comment: “I’ve ... messed something up.” You might’ve been on the right track. Show your work and then someone can tell you where your mistake was.

Comment: How do you know that the line isn’t vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the distance between the two given parallel lines is $d=\frac2{\sqrt5}$ and the slope normal to them is $m=2$. Let $m’$ be the slope of the unknown line and $\theta$ the angle between the given lines and the unknown line. Then, $\cos\theta=\frac d5=\frac2{5\sqrt5}$ and

$$\tan\theta = \pm \frac{11}2 = \frac{m-m’}{1+mm’}$$

which yields $m’ = -\frac7{24},\>-\frac34$. Use the point-slope formula below to obtain the equations of the lines

$$y-4=m’(x+5)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!